# Reading in Excel Data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to read in data from an excel file using VBA but keep getting the following error message :

> object variable or with block variable not set.

I want to read in the data from the excel file and then write certain parts for the data to a new table.

This is my starting point:

[image]

Comment: You Dim'ed your Workbook variable, but you never Set it to anything, so it has no value. It doesn't know which workbook you are talking about. An object with no value cannot be referenced.

Comment: It's better to post code not pictures of code. In that excerpt you haven't defined `myworkbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below might be a better starting point, although if you're reading data from one workbook and writing it to another you will greatly benefit from another set of Workbook/Worksheet objects - i.e. read from `srcWorkbook` and `srcWorksheet` and write to `destWorkbook` and `destWorksheet` perhaps.

```
Public Function OpenExcelFile(strFilePath As String) As Boolean
    
    Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim myWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)
    Set myWorksheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    With myWorksheet
        .Range("J8").Value = "I am here"
    End With
    
End Function
```

Ultimately, we'd need to see what you expect from it and how you're going to use this function (should it just be a `Sub`?)